# bash: reading text from a string one character at a time

Tags: linux, bash, file, variables, while-loop

i have a script to read a file one character at the time
this is the script i use

```
INPUT=/path/
while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do
    echo $char
done < "$INPUT"
```

it works fine only i cant find out how to store every character into a variable
im looking for something like

`N$X=$char`

where X=the count or characters and $char=the character

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As a general thing, having variables like `N1`, `N2`, etc... in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and hoping to access them like `N$i` with `i` another variable is very bad. The cure for this lies in arrays. Here's how I would solve your problem using arrays instead:

```
n=()
i=0
while read -r -n1 n[i]; do
    echo "Character $i is ${n[i]}"
    ((++i))
done < "$INPUT"
```

At this point, you have your characters in the array `n` (well, not all of them). You can have access to character `k+1` with

```
${n[k]}
```

(remember that array indexes start from 0).

---

Another possibility is to slurp everything in a string, it's as simple as this:

```
string=$( < "$INPUT" )
```

and you can have access to character `k+1` with

```
${n:k:1}
```

(taking the substring of length 1 starting at index `k`). Looping on all characters could be done as:

```
for ((k=0;k<${#string};++k)); do
    echo "Character $k is '${string:k:1}'"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
X=0
while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do
    eval "N$X=\$char"
    X=`expr $X + 1`
done < "$INPUT"
```

At the end of the loop, `X0`, `X1`, `X2`, etc. will contain the various characters that have been read in.

Comment: Doesn't that fail whenever the input-file contains whitespace?

Comment: @ruakh Nope. I checked with spaces and it worked fine. Note that the `$char` in the eval isn't expanded until the actual assignment is evaluated, because there is a backslash before the dollar.

Comment: @JamesHolderness: Yeah, I noted it, but . . . oh, I see. I always forget that word-splitting doesn't take place on the right-hand-side of an assignment.